# Section break deletes graphic style in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I used two section breaks to allow one of my pages to be in landscape format. However, said section breaks cause the graphic style (graphic style meaning the borders for lack of a better word) to disappear for the next pages.

I've tried saving/reapplying the theme and such but it doesn't seem to work. And none of the tips I found online address the particular problem.

I would like the landscape page to be blank but the next rest to be in the same style.

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Here's what it looks like]

[And here's a link to download a sample](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ctx1keosidc6j32ork1k8/Fond-de-plan.docx?rlkey=5du10xbqle4fhl1fbew7so6jz&dl=0)

I must add that I obtain the theme by opening a document I made as a template and then saving a copy, so the theme doesn't really exist in my word app though I tried doing it in hindsight and it didn't work.

Comment: Page borders are section properties. This is not a "Theme" as that term is used in Word. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44 Can you edit your question to add a link to a sampled document?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Hi thank you for your answer i'll look into it, I edited the questioned to add a sample as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've examined your sample.

The border is not a Word border but rather a series of layered shapes that are anchored in the header. These are not relative to the margins but fixed.

Your first section has the setting "different first page" to allow for your cover page. This setting is continued when you start a new section. Turn the setting off for your landscape page. You will see your border, set for a portrait page.

Before you start changing anything, create another new portrait section following. Then in both Sections 2 and 3 turn off the options to link to previous in both the headers and footers. That way, changes you may make to section 2 will not mess up the borders in the next portrait section.

Then, you can start moving your graphics around in the header of your landscape page.

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/frkwbjmezqh4d0felhz30/Fond-de-plan.docx?rlkey=hqza608aww1plesu1tfr8axoq&dl=0) to my modifications to your sample, where I started moving some of them.

Here is my [recap of header and footer settings](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know you could access the shapes in this way. Your last reference is really interesting and will most certainly prove useful the next time I have troubles with word ! Thanks again for the time and efforts.

Comment: You are welcome.